# IP to country without database

Tags: ip-geolocation

As we all know, there are many databases that can be used to return the country from a given IP address. I'm wondering about how do those database providers get these info from? who tells them that this IP address is located in that country and not another? is there a script that resolves these IPs or do they get many databases from every ISP and compile them into one? anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those databases are based primary on the information from the five [RIRs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry) that actually manage, allocate and register the ip addresses space. They also manage Autonomous System (AS) numbers within a defined region. The RIRs are :

- African Network Information Centre (AfriNIC)
- American Registry for Internet Numbers (ARIN)
- Asia-Pacific Network Information Centre (APNIC)
- Latin America and Caribbean Network Information Centre (LACNIC)
- RIPE Network Coordination Centre (RIPE NCC)

This method is not perfect and is improved by various datamining, database merging between database maintainers and other methods such as analysis of user submitted data.

Comment: both answers are interesting! but is anyone able to get and compile the databases legally?

Comment: It's available to public. RIPEs daily database snapshots are available at ftp://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/dbase/ripe.db.gz

Comment: ok I got the file but after extraction it became 2.7GB with .db extention. how can I use this?

Comment: More information can be found at the respective RIRs homepage. For example for RIPEs database there is a faq section on their homepage that links to this document on what the database file contains: http://www.ripe.net/db/support/RIPE-DB-Getting_started.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I suspect they start at the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/numbers/) site to find the regional numbering authorities and work there way down to compile the info.

They also have this link which contains some top level info in xml format: http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml